# Linq : combining left join and group by

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two datatables **tabRealisation** and **tabPrevision**, i want apply a left join to have a datatable how contains all columns :

This is what i tried :

```
    Dim query1 =
(From r In tabRealisation.AsEnumerable
 Group Join p In tabPrevision.AsEnumerable
 On r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") Equals p.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") And r.Field(Of Integer)("CodeTypeBien") Equals p.Field(Of Integer)("CodeTypeBien") And r.Field(Of Integer)("month") Equals p.Field(Of Integer)("month") And r.Field(Of String)("TitreFoncier") Equals p.Field(Of String)("TitreFoncier")
 Into Group
 Let p = Group.FirstOrDefault
 Where r.Field(Of Integer)("month") >= 1 And r.Field(Of Integer)("month") <= 12
 Select an = r.Field(Of Integer)("year"),
        mois = r.Field(Of Integer)("month"),
        code_part = r.Field(Of Integer)("code_part"),
        TitreFoncier = r.Field(Of String)("TitreFoncier"),
        CodeTypeBien = r.Field(Of Integer)("CodeTypeBien"),
        UniteStock= r.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteStock"),
        CAStock= r.Field(Of Double?)("CAStock"),
        UniteVentePrev = If(p Is Nothing, 0, p.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteVentePrev")),
        ).ToList
```

Now i want do a group by **"code_part"** with left join to have sum of columns from **tabRealisation** and **tabPrevision** not from **query1** :

[image]

Comment: What's the question? You only tell what you intend to do.

Comment: Yes i hope to have a proposition for my need.